# Whenever I move from Navigation menu to the Dropdown the Dropdown disappears after hover

Tags: html, css, dropdown

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navigation {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  background-color: #390238;
}

.navigation::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.navigation-primary {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
}

.navigation-primary--item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12rem;
  position: relative;
}

.navigation-primary--item a {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: #eee;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.navigation-primary--item a:hover {
  background-color: #520350;
}

.navigation-primary--item a:hover+ul {
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 0;
}

.navigation-primary--item-main {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: #390238;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.navigation-primary--item-main-sub {
  list-style: none;
  widows: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.navigation-primary--item-main-sub a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

.navigation-primary--item-main-sub a:hover {
  background-color: #520350;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
    <title>Navigation Dropdown Using Float</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navigation">
        <ul class="navigation-primary">
            <li class="navigation-primary--item"><a href="#">Home</a>
                <ul class="navigation-primary--item-main">
                    <li class="navigation-primary--item-main-sub"><a href="#">Home Subitem</a></li>
                    <li class="navigation-primary--item-main-sub"><a href="#">Home Subitem</a></li>
                    <li class="navigation-primary--item-main-sub"><a href="#">Home Subitem</a></li>
                    <li class="navigation-primary--item-main-sub"><a href="#">Home Subitem</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="navigation-primary--item"><a href="#">About Us</a>
                <ul class="navigation-primary--item-main">
                    <li class="navigation-primary--item-main-sub"><a href="#">About Us Subitem</a></li>
                    <li class="navigation-primary--item-main-sub"><a href="#">About Us Subitem</a></li>
                    <li class="navigation-primary--item-main-sub"><a href="#">About Us Subitem</a></li>
                    <li class="navigation-primary--item-main-sub"><a href="#">About Us Subitem</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="navigation-primary--item"><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
                <ul class="navigation-primary--item-main">
                    <li class="navigation-primary--item-main-sub"><a href="#">Contact Us Subitem</a></li>
                    <li class="navigation-primary--item-main-sub"><a href="#">Contact Us Subitem</a></li>
                    <li class="navigation-primary--item-main-sub"><a href="#">Contact Us Subitem</a></li>
                    <li class="navigation-primary--item-main-sub"><a href="#">Contact Us Subitem</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="navigation-primary--item"><a href="#">LogOut</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Created a dropdown menu and when i hover dropdown appears and after hover when i move the  cursor to the drop it disappears.
NOTE: THERE IS NO GAP BETWEEN DROPDOWN AND NAVBAR

Created a dropdown menu and when i hover dropdown appears and after hover when i move the  cursor to the drop it disappears.
NOTE: THERE IS NO GAP BETWEEN DROPDOWN AND NAVBAR

Created a dropdown menu and when i hover dropdown appears and after hover when i move the  cursor to the drop it disappears.
NOTE: THERE IS NO GAP BETWEEN DROPDOWN AND NAVBAR

Comment: your hover css is based on your `<a>` tag when it should be based on the container element `.navigation-primary--item`

Comment: It worked. Thanks :).
By the way,  .navigation-primary--item and it child element <a> both have the same dimensions then why it's not working on child element <a>.

Comment: Because of how these things work out. When you hover over the `<a>`, the hover styles are applied and your dropdown menu shows. Problem is when you move your mouse to the dropdown, you are no longer hovering over the `<a>`, so it hides.

Comment: also you should really use `display: none` to hide the menu, otherwise people can still click the menu items they just can't see them (in place of opacity)

Answer (score 0):

I've had that problem before and don't remember how I solved it, but probably it was to just raise the submenu blocks up a pixel or two, with something like a negative margin-top.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution which updates one CSS rule.

Change the rule:

```
 .navigation-primary--item a:hover+ul {
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 0;
}
```

To this:

```
 .navigation-primary--item:hover > * {
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 0;
  }
```

Basically, apply the rule to all children when the parent is in the hover state. The parent will be in this state when you are hovering over it or anything inside it.

Comment: Tried that as well. By doing that when i hover it doesn't even display the  dropdown menu.

Comment: That's weird. I tested it and it worked for me. Are you sure you removed the old rule completely?